# topological space on a ﬁnite set

Tags: general-topology

prove or disprove

If (X,T ) is a topological space on a ﬁnite set X, then T contains only ﬁnitely many open sets.

Comment: The topology $T$ does not necessary have $2^n$ elements, it is a subset of the powerset of $X$ which have $2^n$, then $|T| \leq 2^n$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$T$ is finite because it is a subset of the power set $P(X)$ which has $2^n$ elements. But that doesn't mean that $T$ itself has $2^n$ elements, it could have fewer.

Comment: $T$ is a subset of $P(X)$, and $P(X)$ is a finite set, so yes, $T$ is finite. However, it makes no sense to call $T$ an "open set". The **elements** of $T$, each of which is a subset of $X$, are called "open subsets of $X$".

Comment: The power set $P(X)$ has $2^n$ elements, therefore $P(X)$ is a finite set. $T$ is a subset of $P(X)$. Every subset of a finite set is also finite. Therefore, $T$ is a finite set.

Comment: @de.rise indeed. $\mathscr{P}(X)$ is finite when $X$ is and so is any subset of it, like a topology on $X$. It's as simple as that.